# JQuery fadeIn() callback executes before animation is complete when calling function

Tags: jquery

I saw lots of posts about this on the site but most of them are for people trying to do multiple animations, I tried some of the solutions and narrowed it down to this, I have one box I'm trying to fade, for some reason if I put the function in the code directly it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div3').fadeIn(1000, function(){alert('Done')});
});
```

But if I call a function that does the exact same thing, it alerts before the animation starts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div3').fadeIn(1000, test());

    function test(){
        alert("Done");
    };
});
```

I have tried putting the test() function in and out of the (document).ready() with the same results. I have no idea whats causing this, it's probably something small I'm missing but for the life of me I can't see it. Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function right away, not referencing it. Remove the parenthesis

```
$('#div3').fadeIn(1000, test);
```

Comment: That worked, but I thought you always had to put the () at the end when calling a function, this is just weird.

Comment: You always add the parenthesis to **call** the function, but in this case you don't want to call the function, you want to reference it so it's called later, and then you leave the parenthesis out, otherwise it's called immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function test there, pass function reference instead and it should work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#div3').fadeIn(1000, test);
                    //--------^--here remove the parenthesis
   function test(){
     alert("Done");
   };
 });
```